Why is my microphone not found by web apps on chrome but mic is detected by OS?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and for some reason the mic stopped working in whatsapp web or any other implementation of that website. now I get this message

what's odd to me is that in the settings, it does appear like the mic exists for the os (the picture below shows how it looks if I have my earpiece connected to jack, the earpiece does have a mic that appears to work given the feedback seen on the picture

If I remove the earpiece connected to jack.. It shows this

which again gives me the indication that the os is seeing the mic so I'm not sure why is it that it does not show up for whatsapp web, whether I'm using the earpiece or nothing at all.
I have to say this was not the case before, but I can't tell what changed to cause this issue.
Also, the whatsapp web is on chrome, permissions to the mic were manually given yet, it still won't work

I tried google meet and again the microfono is not getting detected by chrome
Last but not least, if use firefox, I get prompted to give the site mic permission and after that it works ok. I could possible switch to firefox but I'd really like to get this working again with chrome along with any other app that uses whatsapp web like  whatsapp for linux or ferdium which I was using until recently.
any help troubleshooting this is greatly appreciate it as it's driving me nuts

Are you using Firefox or Chrome (or something else)? If using Firefox, switching to the PPA based apt package may help https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/124466

you beat me to the update of the question and now I got a -1.
I'm on chrome and until recently I was also using whatsapp for linux and ferdium..
in firefox I don't get that problem.

I didn't downvote. Please don't take downvotes without comment seriously. There are some users on this site who just downvote and leave without any feedback, and that does not help anyone.

sorry @ArchismanPanigrahi It's a bit frustrating when you try to make a question relevant and proper but then I get downvoted like that, and since your comment and the downvote happened almost at the same time, I just assumed that it was you.. my bad.

Given that I have no clue or way to check what might have changed in chrome and since the issue is associated with Chrome specifically as mic works ok on firefox, I realized that one obvious option was to remove / purge chrome completely and proceed to reinstall.
Once I reinstalled it, chrome was able to detect my mic ok again.
Hope it helps someone.
